# Why there is no nsenter in util-linux?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, networking

I frequently using `nsenter` command for my purposes in my main system under Arch Linux. Now I have to work on Ubuntu to test my apps on it, but there isn't `nsenter` in util-linux. Maybe it's a separate package?

UPD. Ok, I checked that version of `util-linux` in Ubuntu is still much older than 2.23. How can I install new version of package without any after problems on Ubuntu?

Comment: If you happen to want it for using it with Docker then just follow the guide here https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

Comment: @Sylvain I don't see the point of adding 14.04 as a tag given that 13.xy was removed.

Comment: @muru, actually `nsenter` is available in 14.10 (See the [package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/util-linux/filelist) for `utils-linux`). Hence the 14.04 tag to this question.

Comment: @SylvainPineau maybe, but does it make sense adding tag to a question half a year old? Why not 12.04 then?

Comment: @muru I didn't check if compiling 2.24 as suggested in my original answer works on 12.04. So I preferred to restrict the scope of this Q/A to 14.04. The point of keeping it up-to-date is obviously that this solution is not needed as of 14.10

Comment: @SylvainPineau Eh, what? Your solution isn't tested for 12.04 so modify the question? O.o you should edit your answer instead.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update**:

As of 14.10, the [`util-linux`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/util-linux) provides the `nsenter` command. The solution below has been tested with 14.04.

---

The Debian/Ubuntu version is as you said quite old now, even in Trusty.

There's an opened [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/1012081) and so far no progress unfortunately.

You could try to build it from source:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.24/util-linux-2.24.1.tar.gz -qO - | tar -xz -C ~/Downloads
```

Make sure to install the following build dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libslang2-dev gettext zlib1g-dev libselinux1-dev debhelper lsb-release pkg-config po-debconf autoconf automake autopoint libtool
```

And just run in the source directory (`~/Downloads/util-linux-2.24.1`):

```
./autogen.sh

./configure && make
```

---

### **IMPORTANT**

Do **NOT** `sudo make install` this package on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS until it is officially ready for use, as it definitely demands an unavailable version of `libmount`, breaking your boot. (If you do this, reinstall the `mount` package before rebooting your machine, if you can.)

<sub>Credits: [Trevor Alexander](https://askubuntu.com/users/129616/trevor-alexander) for his [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/439056/why-there-is-no-nsenter-in-util-linux/439065#comment727477_439065).</sub>

---

Finally you'll get:

```
sylvain@sylvain-ThinkPad-T430s:~/Downloads/util-linux-2.24.1$ ./nsenter -V
nsenter from util-linux 2.24.1
```

**Note**: as nsenter is not available in the ubuntu util-linux version, you can install just this file in /usr/bin (or sbin):

```
sudo cp ./nsenter /usr/bin
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but I get an error while `./configure`, because there is no such file. I'm getting `Could not locate the pkg-config autoconf macros.` if trying to use `configure.ac` file.

Comment: Try with the [tarball](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.24/util-linux-2.24.1.tar.gz) instead. Make sure you have both `pkg-config` and `autoconf` installed too

Comment: Also, if you get an error about missing python when you actually do have python, make sure to install `python2.7-dev` package

Comment: Keep in mind the 2.24.x and newer versions are all in "experimental" for good reason, they probably haven't been uploaded to Unstable in Debian due to bugs and issues and aren't ready.  As a result of that, and or because it's just too new, it's not in Ubuntu.  (NOTE: Utopic looks like it'll have a newer version of this package)

Comment: IMPORTANT: Do NOT `sudo make install` this package on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS until it is officially ready for use, as it definitely demands an unavailable version of `libmount`, breaking your boot. (If you do this, reinstall the `mount` package before rebooting your machine, if you can.)

Comment: @TrevorAlexander Thank you, I've added your comment to my answer

Comment: It's not going to break anything to put nsenter in /usr/bin, but usual practice is to leave that for stuff installed from apt packages, and install other stuff in /usr/local/bin.  It mostly just makes it easier to see what custom stuff you have set up.

Comment: Is `utils-linux` a typo of `util-linux`? (Not confident enough to edit the answer, but as far as I can tell, it is.)

Comment: @DreadPirateShawn It's a typo, good catch. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

If you use docker you can install nsenter in a container and then copy the nsenter command to the host.

From my gist: https://gist.github.com/mbn18/0d6ff5cb217c36419661

```
# Ubuntu 14.04 don't have nsenter - the straight forward way required me to install build tools and etc.
# I preferred to keep the system clean and install nsenter in a container and then copy the command to the host
# Note - its also possible to run nsenter from a container (didn't tried) https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

# start a container
docker run --name nsenter -it ubuntu:14.04 bash

## in the docker
apt-get update
apt-get install git build-essential libncurses5-dev libslang2-dev gettext zlib1g-dev libselinux1-dev debhelper lsb-release pkg-config po-debconf autoconf automake autopoint libtool

git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git util-linux
cd util-linux/

./autogen.sh
./configure --without-python --disable-all-programs --enable-nsenter
make

## from different shell - on the host
docker cp nsenter:/util-linux/nsenter /usr/local/bin/
docker cp nsenter:/util-linux/bash-completion/nsenter /etc/bash_completion.d/nsenter
```

Comment: By "keeping host system clean" you mean obviating the need to install `build-essential` and the other libraries in the `apt-get` command above, right? That's actually very interesting if yes, didn't know of `docker cp`. This is great for building all sorts of things as binaries without polluting the host.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Docker 1.3 you can use Docker exec to enter a Docker container :

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash
```

as mentioned in the repo for https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter